# How do I prevent $.ajax from adding [] to my key names (without processData: false)?

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I try to use `$.ajax` to POST a data dictionary like:

```
{
    list: ["fake_id_0"],
    mapType: "fakeToRealId"
}
```

jQuery does something strange to it; it transforms the data into:

```
{
    list[]: ["fake_id_0"],
    mapType: "fakeToRealId"
}
```

As you can see, it adds brackets to the `list` key, but not the `mapType` key.  Now in a 
general REST sense, yes it is common for people to name keys with array values with brackets ... but *my* server doesn't work that way, so if I try to POST `list[]` I have problems.

I have tracked this problem down to `$.ajax`'s handling of the parseData option, in this bit of code:

```
// Convert data if not already a string
if ( s.data && s.processData && typeof s.data !== "string" ) {
    s.data = jQuery.param( s.data, s.traditional );
}
```

and if I use `processData: false` it does skip that block ... but then it also doesn't URLEncode my data for me.

So, my question is: how do make `$.ajax` calls with `processData: true` without having jQuery modify my key names on me?  Or failing that, how do I use `processData: false`, but still get every effect from that option *except* the bracket-adding?

P.S. Or, if this is all non-standard jQuery behavior, being caused by some plug-in I have, please let me know that instead :-)

*** EDIT ***

I answered my own question, then deleted that answer because I realized that it was flawed.  I answered that setting the option `traditional:true` (in the `$.ajax` call)  fixes the brackets, and it does ... but it also has a side effect, which is that it will not serialize nested objects.

So my revised question is: how do make `$.ajax` calls with `processData: true` without having jQuery modify my key names on me AND without disabling its serialization of nested properties?  In other words, how do I have jQuery do everything the same as it currently does ... except not add brackets to my keys?

Comment: honestly this looks like an official bug/problem/feature request issue. Have you submitted this to jquery's bugs?

Comment: @user1737909 I'm not sure how *any* HTML would be helpful in this case; this is a purely JS problem with no manifestations in the DOM.

Comment: @relipse I did just file a bug (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13975) but given that A) they're probably not going to fix it (this behavior goes back pretty far in jQuery, and the team is even less likely to change existing behavior now that they are post-1.0), and B) even if they do fix it it won't get fixed for awhile ... I was hoping that I might find an intermediary solution.  Also, I'm not exactly certain that my assessment of the situation is accurate; it seems entirely possible that someone will say "well all that's because of unrelated option X that you didn't know about", or something.

Comment: Aah my bad, I thought you were serializing a form and you got something like that ^^'. I think I saw an issue already

Comment: @machineghost Well for me php automatically puts this into an array on the server end, since you are not using php, either modify your server code or you can't use $.post until it gets fixed, or even make a copy of the .post() function and fix the keys before they get sent... right?

Comment: @user1737909 I'm not using PHP, and it's non-trivial in my (Python/Django) app to change every server API.  Whatever fix I implement has to be client-side.  However, I don't want to implement a fix (eg. `traditional: true`) that ends up causing more side effects/problems down the road, thus my question here.

Comment: @relipse Just to follow up on my earlier comment, the bug was closed as expected.

Comment: sounds like you'll be writing your own $.post() then, you can always add it as a plugin to share with the rest of the jquery community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you realized this is not a bug. The brackets were put there specifically to solve problems with multi-level objects, after version 1.4 I believe. You can have a look to .param() itself to understand why. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

I believe what you want is not possible and good way to verify is to try end encode one string by hand. I believe you will not be able to encode it in way that is uniquely decodable, without the brackets.

To amend my answer, quoting from the above link

> Note: Because some frameworks have limited ability to parse serialized arrays, developers should exercise caution when passing an obj argument that contains objects or arrays nested within another array.
>
> Note: Because there is no universally agreed-upon specification for param strings, it is not possible to encode complex data structures using this method in a manner that works ideally across all languages supporting such input. Use JSON format as an alternative for encoding complex data instead.

So if you server is ready to parse json, you can then send your request like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'something',
    type: 'GET',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However ... "I believe you will not be able to encode it in way that is uniquely decodable, without the brackets." ... you assume that I want a universal JSON encoder, but that isn't a requirement.  I promise, my server will happily take JSON like `foo: [bar, baz]` and parse it just fine *if* I can get such JSON to it.  My problem is that I can't get generate such JSON, even though there is no technical reason why JQuery can't produce `foo: [bar, baz]` instead of `foo[]: [bar, baz]` (and in fact it can with `traditional: true` ... but that has other side effects).

Comment: Well, I believe that this is the un-encoded object. You server will accept the JSON, but the problem is to get it to the server. When you change that to a valid url parameter string it becomes `foo=bar&foo=baz`. If you have nested items foo[bar, {a:1}] you cannot say foo=bar&foo=a=1

Comment: Try sending it as JSON and see if that helps (amended answer).

Comment: By the way, if you know what you want and you do not want to cover all bases, you could write your own function to transform objects to url encoded strings. That could also solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's already implied by the question body, but here's how you avoid this wonderful feature of jQuery's. If you have:

```
$.get(api_url, {my_param: my_arguments})
```

change it to:

```
$.get(api_url, $.param({my_param: my_arguments}, true))
```

Answer (score 0):

The property data can accept object as well as string. So in order to avoid jquery making changes to your variable name by adding [] i.e abc -> abc[] then you need to pass all arguments as string.

For Example :

```
var data = {
      "test":[1,2,3],
      flag:true 
  }
  let str = 'test=1&test=2&test=3&flag=true'
  $.ajax({
    url : 'API/url',
    type : 'POST',
    data : str,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(){do stuff}
  });
```

Though , you can add all these arguments into a string and assign it to data. And for multiple values in list, those can be added using loop by adding them to string at each iteration